# Create a "normal" class from class with all `static` methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Once upon a time I wrote a Singleton class. The implementation is a class consisting only of static methods - I added an exception on `__init__` for illustration purposes only, I do not even have an `__init__`, but will need one later:

```
class A:
    x = 3
    def __init__(self): raise Exception('Oh no you did not!')
    @staticmethod
    def m1():
        print(A.x)
    @staticmethod
    def m2(n):
        A.y=8
```

Fast forward some years, and now I need to create instances of the Singleton  - please no judgement :). The requirements:

1. I cannot forego the Singleton version. I used it too many times, so I cannot just rewrite it.
2. The new class should access an object variable where the original accessed a class one
3. All `staticmethod` decorators need to be removed
4. All methods need an additional `self` argument.
5. Need to define an `__init__` method
6. I do not want to copy paste and fix the paste - the class is long, and will be subject to future changes that should always apply to both versions, holding to the above requirements. As such construction of the new version should be dynamic, and rely on the original version (I already screwed myself once not thinking ahead).

Solutions may be implemented in the original class, but I think it might be impossible, so a function taking the original class and spewing out a new one would probably be the way to go:

```
class A:
    x = 3 #No need to touch class variable definitions. 
    def __init__(self): pass #Maybe the init method will be an argument

    def m1(self):
       print(self.x)

    def m2(self,n):
       self.y = n
```

Any solution (hacky or not) that dynamically creates stuff is fine. I am currently looking at building this using `inspect`, though I am not sure it will pan out.

Comment: I agree with "I already screwed myself once not thinking ahead", which is exactly why I disagree with "I used it too many times, so I cannot just rewrite it". Fix it now. Refactor the code you already have. Doing anything else (eg coming up with hacky workarounds) is simply shooting yourself in the foot. Even if you get a workaround to work *now* it can come around and bite you *later*

Comment: @DeepSpace I wish, and completely agree. My *time/usage breadth->0* right now. I cannot afford to start refactoring right now with a chance of breaking something that works. I do hope to get to a full refactor in a few weeks time, but this is something I will be solving today, one way or another. The good thing is any new code using the new objects will likely be unaffected by a refactor later, though, as you hint, I can never be sure.

Comment: How many static methods are we talking about? I can't imagine it will take *that* long to just copy it and make the necessary changes by hand. The statements "will be subject to future changes that should always apply to both versions" and "I hope to get to a full refactor in a few weeks" are somewhat mutually exclusive; commit to the refactor in lieu of trying to keep two parallel code bases in sync.

Comment: You can use static/class methods as instace methods (no need to rewrite them, if that helps). Also, shooting ideas, you can use a child class with instance methods passing them with `super()`, until you fix them

Comment: @Mstaino `A` is hard-coded in the static methods; how do you plan on using those as instance methods?

Comment: @chepner Not really, changes are on a daily basis, so in a few weeks time there could be a few mistakes especially if I am refactoring and the classes are not identical (up to the static stuff). I am getting the "really do not do this" vibe though, and thanks for the input, I will see how hard it might be to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your great ideas, they helped me implement what I wanted, before I hit a duh moment:

**I renamed the original class, fixed it to work normally, and created an instance of it with the same old name.**

All code that imported the file used the same name as is, with no modification whatsoever. I really should have thought of this before. Seriously.

---

**In case someone really wants the fruit of everyone's work, this is what I did using all the ideas** (somewhat tested)

```
import inspect
import re
def method_remove_static(m,cls_name):
    source = inspect.getsourcelines(m)[0]
    for i in range(len(source)):
        if 'staticmethod' in source[i]:
            del source[i]
            break
    for j in range(i,len(source)):
        if ' def ' in source[i]:
            source[i] = source[i].replace('(','(self,',1).lstrip()
            break

    return re.sub(r'(?<!\w)%s\.'%cls_name,'self.',''.join(source))

def class_remove_indentation(cls):
    source = inspect.getsourcelines(cls)[0]
    for i in range(len(source)):
        if ' class ' in source[i]:
            source[i] = source[i].lstrip()
            break
    return ''.join(source)

def regular_var(x):
    return (not inspect.ismethod(x) and
            not inspect.isbuiltin(x) and
            not inspect.ismethoddescriptor(x) and
            not inspect.isclass(x) and
            not inspect.isfunction(x))

#MAIN FUNCTION
def class_remove_static(cls,init = None,context = {}):
    class newCls:
        if init is not None:
            __init__ = init

    #Inner classes
    for name,incls in inspect.getmembers(cls,predicate=lambda x: inspect.isclass(x)):
        if name == "__class__": continue
        exec(class_remove_indentation(incls),context)
        setattr(newCls,name,context[name])

    __init__ = init
    #static methods are listed as functions
    for name,method in inspect.getmembers(cls,predicate=inspect.isfunction):
        if name == "__init__": continue
        exec(method_remove_static(method,cls.__name__),context)
        setattr(newCls,name,context[name])

    #Class variables defined at time of call (almost)
    for name,var in inspect.getmembers(cls,predicate=regular_var):
        if (name == '__doc__'     or name == '__module__' or
            name == '__weakref__' or name =='__dict__'): continue
        setattr(newCls,name,var)

    return newCls
```

This literally re-compiles the source code. I am sure the regular expression sub can break some use-cases, but it worked for me. Provide your `locals()` as context if your class is based on variables in the module you are using this, and an optional `init` function that must accept at least one parameter (colloquially named `self`).

The is a simple search and replace, with the very un-loved `exec`. Use at your own discretion if you really need it.

Comment: Note this solution is highly specialized. For one, I only have static methods, no regular ones, and the regular expression I am sure might break on some examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is sufficient, but I think the following modification can be used both as your original singleton and as a normal class. There's a fair amount of boilerplate, but it's isolated to the class, not the code that uses the class.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def m1(*args):
        # A.m1() means args will be empty
        if args and isinstance(args[0], A):
            self = args[0]
        else:
            self = A

        print(self.x)

    def m2(*args):
        if isinstance(args[0], A):
            self, n = args
        else:
            self = A
            n = args[0]

        self.y = n
```

Essentially, you'll do the following to each method:

1. Strip the `staticmethod` decorator
2. Replace each method's argument list with `*args`
3. Manually identify if the first argument (if any) is an instance of A. If it is not, set `self = A`, otherwise, `self = args[0]`.
4. Manually create local variables for each of the old parameters, using the appropriate element of `*args` based on what you find in step 3.

For example, `A.m1()` results in `print(A.x)`, while `a = A(); a.mi()` results in `print(a.x)`. Likewise, `A.m2(8)` is `A.y = 8` while `a.m2(8)` is `a.y = 8`.

I would be hesitant to try to automate this further; you'll probably spend more time identifying and trying to work around corner cases than you would by updating each method manually.

Answer (score 2):

It will be hard to convert a static singleton class where all side effects can only affect the class itself to a normal class where side effects would only affect the instance objects. But it is possible to do the opposite: convert a normal class to a singleton static class simply by making the static class own a unique instance of the normal class and delegates all its methods call and attribute accesses to it.

A metaclass could do the job. This one creates a special attribute `_own` to hold an instance of its *model* class, explicitely creates methods for it with the appropriate signature (it also keeps docstrings if any) just delegating calls to `_own`, and also delegates all attribute accesses to `_own`

```
import inspect

class Singletoner(type):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):           # delegates attribute accesses
        return getattr(self._own, attr)
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
        obj = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)
        X = kwds['model']           # the model class is expected with the model keyword
        obj._own = X()
        for name, func in inspect.getmembers(X, inspect.isfunction):
            if name != '__init__':
                _trans(name, func, obj)   # tranfers all methods other than __init__
        return obj

def _trans(name, func, clazz):
    def f(*args,**kwargs):
            return func(clazz._own, *args, **kwargs)
    sig = inspect.signature(func)   # copy signature just removing the initial param
    parameters = sig.parameters
    params = [t[1] for t in list(sig.parameters.items())[1:]]
    f.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters = params)
    f.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    setattr(clazz, name, f)
```

With your example, the non singleton class would b:

```
class A:
    x = 3
    def __init__(self): pass
    def m1(self):
        print(self.x)
    def m2(self, n):
        self.y=n
```

Its singleton delegator could be declared as:

```
class B(metaclass=Singletoner, model=A):
    pass
```

You can they use it simply:

```
>>> B.m1()
3
>>> B.m2(6)
>>> B.x
3
>>> B.y
6
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.signature(B.m2))
(n)
>>> print(inspect.signature(B.m1))
()
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems the biggest problem is having the method call `self.x` instead of `A.x` This is gonna be a silly idea, but you said hacky fixes are okay, so could we just backup all the values for class attributes, change them to match the instance attributes, then call the staticmethod, then restore all the values? If you would allow that, something like this might work:

```
import types

class A:
    x=3

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def m1():
        print(A.x)
    @staticmethod
    def m2(n):
        A.y = n

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        Aattr = getattr(type(self),name)            # get the class attribute of the same name to see if it is a function
        if isinstance(Aattr,types.FunctionType):
            def hackyfunction(self,*args,**kwargs):
                ... # copy all previous values of A attributes, replace them with instance attributes
                returnvalue = Aattr(*args, **kwargs)
                ... # change everything back
                return returnvalue
            method = types.MethodType(hackyfunction, self)
            return method
        # now it can't be a function, so just return normally. self.name will default to A.name if there is no instance attribute
        return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
```